# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 c# MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm taking data from a datagridview and from other variables, and I want to save it in my database, but Im getting the error: Column count doesn't match value at row 1. 
the code:

```
 MySqlCommand comando2 = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("Insert into 
 producto_vendido (IdProducto_Vendido, IdVenta, IdProducto, Nombre_Producto, 
 Precio_Unitario, Cantidad_Vendida, Pago_Total) values  ("@d0,@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6)"), conexion);
            comando2.Prepare();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv1.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d0",pSocio.IdProductoVendido);
                    comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1",IdVenta)
                    comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", row.Cells[0].Value);
                    comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", row.Cells[1].Value);
                    comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", row.Cells[2].Value);
                    comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", row.Cells[3].Value);
                    comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d6", row.Cells[4].Value);
                    comando2.ExecuteNonQuery(); <--- (visual show the error here )
                    comando2.Parameters.Clear();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet?

Comment: yes I solved but thanks